# Error on pgr_dijkstra

Tags: qgis, postgis, pgrouting

Using Postgresql 9.6, pgrouting 2.4.1  when I want to use pgr_dijkstra on a osm2pgrouting parsed database I get the following error:

`ERROR:  Error, columns 'source', 'target' must be of type int4, 'cost' must be of type float8
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function _pgr_parameter_check(text,text,boolean) line 40 at RAISE
PL/pgSQL function pgr_dijkstra(text,integer,integer,boolean,boolean) line 7 at assignment`

I read that in previous versions this could happen, and tried to change the types alreay, using Qgis. I am not succeding.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

This usually happens if you are using one of the signatures that has has_rcost argument. If you passed in has_rcost boolean, then get rid of it and make sure your SQL contains both a cost and reverse_cost field if you want reverse cost to be used.

Would also be helpful if you provided the exact query you are running. It will be easier to see what is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I guess I just made a mistake, 
Finally got it right:

`SELECT * FROM pgr_Dijkstra(
  'SELECT gid AS id, source, target, length_m As cost FROM public.ways',
  1 ,77465,  FALSE 
);`

The thing was that I added an extra argument, thus resulting in a error.
Like:

`SELECT * FROM pgr_Dijkstra(
  'SELECT gid AS id, source, target, length_m As cost FROM public.ways',
  1 ,77465, False, FALSE 
);`

Very happy now to try out new methods!